# JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Tags: python, json, string

I dont know why I am getting this error even after I fix the single quotes

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
asd="[{name:'TokenPurchase',inputs:[{type:'address',name:'buyer',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'eth_sold',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_bought',indexed:!0}],anonymous:!1,type:'event'},{name:'EthPurchase',inputs:[{type:'address',name:'buyer',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_sold',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'eth_bought',indexed:!0}],anonymous:!1,type:'event'},{name:'AddLiquidity',inputs:[{type:'address',name:'provider',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'eth_amount',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'token_amount',indexed:!0}],anonymous:!1,type:'event'},{name:'RemoveLiquidity',inputs:[{type:'address',name:'provider',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'eth_amount',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'token_amount',indexed:!0}],anonymous:!1,type:'event'},{name:'Transfer',inputs:[{type:'address',name:'_from',indexed:!0},{type:'address',name:'_to',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'_value',indexed:!1}],anonymous:!1,type:'event'},{name:'Approval',inputs:[{type:'address',name:'_owner',indexed:!0},{type:'address',name:'_spender',indexed:!0},{type:'uint256',name:'_value',indexed:!1}],anonymous:!1,type:'event'},{name:'setup',outputs:[],inputs:[{type:'address',name:'token_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:175875},{name:'addLiquidity',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'min_liquidity'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_tokens'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'}],constant:!1,payable:!0,type:'function',gas:82605},{name:'removeLiquidity',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'},{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'amount'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_eth'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_tokens'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:116814},{name:'__default__',outputs:[],inputs:[],constant:!1,payable:!0,type:'function'},{name:'ethToTokenSwapInput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'min_tokens'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'}],constant:!1,payable:!0,type:'function',gas:12757},{name:'ethToTokenTransferInput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'min_tokens'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'recipient'}],constant:!1,payable:!0,type:'function',gas:12965},{name:'ethToTokenSwapOutput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'}],constant:!1,payable:!0,type:'function',gas:50455},{name:'ethToTokenTransferOutput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'recipient'}],constant:!1,payable:!0,type:'function',gas:50663},{name:'tokenToEthSwapInput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_eth'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:47503},{name:'tokenToEthTransferInput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_eth'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'recipient'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:47712},{name:'tokenToEthSwapOutput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'eth_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_tokens'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:50175},{name:'tokenToEthTransferOutput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'eth_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_tokens'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'recipient'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:50384},{name:'tokenToTokenSwapInput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_eth_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'token_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:51007},{name:'tokenToTokenTransferInput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_eth_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'recipient'},{type:'address',name:'token_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:51098},{name:'tokenToTokenSwapOutput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_eth_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'token_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:54928},{name:'tokenToTokenTransferOutput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_eth_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'recipient'},{type:'address',name:'token_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:55019},{name:'tokenToExchangeSwapInput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_eth_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'exchange_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:49342},{name:'tokenToExchangeTransferInput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'min_eth_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'recipient'},{type:'address',name:'exchange_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:49532},{name:'tokenToExchangeSwapOutput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_eth_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'exchange_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:53233},{name:'tokenToExchangeTransferOutput',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_bought'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_tokens_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'max_eth_sold'},{type:'uint256',name:'deadline'},{type:'address',name:'recipient'},{type:'address',name:'exchange_addr'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:53423},{name:'getEthToTokenInputPrice',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'eth_sold'}],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:5542},{name:'getEthToTokenOutputPrice',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_bought'}],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:6872},{name:'getTokenToEthInputPrice',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'tokens_sold'}],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:5637},{name:'getTokenToEthOutputPrice',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'eth_bought'}],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:6897},{name:'tokenAddress',outputs:[{type:'address',name:'out'}],inputs:[],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:1413},{name:'factoryAddress',outputs:[{type:'address',name:'out'}],inputs:[],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:1443},{name:'balanceOf',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'address',name:'_owner'}],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:1645},{name:'transfer',outputs:[{type:'bool',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'address',name:'_to'},{type:'uint256',name:'_value'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:75034},{name:'transferFrom',outputs:[{type:'bool',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'address',name:'_from'},{type:'address',name:'_to'},{type:'uint256',name:'_value'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:110907},{name:'approve',outputs:[{type:'bool',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'address',name:'_spender'},{type:'uint256',name:'_value'}],constant:!1,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:38769},{name:'allowance',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[{type:'address',name:'_owner'},{type:'address',name:'_spender'}],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:1925},{name:'name',outputs:[{type:'bytes32',name:'out'}],inputs:[],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:1623},{name:'symbol',outputs:[{type:'bytes32',name:'out'}],inputs:[],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:1653},{name:'decimals',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:1683},{name:'totalSupply',outputs:[{type:'uint256',name:'out'}],inputs:[],constant:!0,payable:!1,type:'function',gas:1713}]"

asd=asd.replace("\'", "\"")

json.loads(asd)
```

Comment: Bigger picture, consider where `asd` comes from and how it got to be invalid JSON in the first place

Comment: Your data is not valid JSON (contain several mistakes). It's also not valid Python. It seems to be valid YAML but missing whitespace characters corrupt the data on parsing. To cut the long story short: you have to fix the data on the source.

Comment: Also, `indexed:!0` is definitely not valid JSON. The exclamation mark usually means `logical not` in languages like C. However, in your case it looks like an indicator for numbers or int's. And as Brad mentioned below, the keys need to be quoted. Was it copied from the logs of another application? Or perhaps an object pickled as text?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so found a way to "fix" the JSON assuming there are only two errors:

1. Double-quotes are missing around key names
2. Numbers prefixed with an exclamation mark (`!`) seem to be booleans (True/False as 1/0)

   - There are other numbers which don't have the '!', like "gas:1713" near the end.
   - So I've assumed that those are regular numbers, and the '!' indicates booleans
   - There seem to be no other occurrences which are not `\0` or `\1` (so things like `\2`, `\5`, `\123`, etc. are not present)

**Disclaimer:** this is not recommended. And I've *not* made the expressions tolerant of extra allowed spaces in JSON. Just for the sample you provided.

Using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and string substitution to fix each of these issues, starting with what you have put:

```
import re

asd = '...'  # from the question

# replace quotes, as you have done, assuming they are only
# around actual strings and not _within_ any strings
asd = asd.replace("\'", "\"")
# becomes:
# [{name:"TokenPurchase",inputs:[{type:"address",name:"buyer",indexed:!0},...]
```

Add quotes around the keys. Again, assuming the sequence of characters `xyz123:` only occurs as *keys*:

```
fixed_keys = re.sub(r'(\w+):', r'"\1":', asd)
# becomes:
# [{"name":"TokenPurchase","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"buyer","indexed":!0},...]
```

Then, convert `\1` to `true` and `\0` to `false`:

```
fixed_trues = fixed_keys.replace('!1', 'true')
fixed_falses = fixed_trues.replace('!0', 'false')
# [{"name":"TokenPurchase","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"buyer","indexed":false},...]
```

It can now be loaded without errors:

```
fixed = json.loads(fixed_falses)
```

Sample of `fixed`:

```
[{'name': 'TokenPurchase',
  'inputs': [{'type': 'address', 'name': 'buyer', 'indexed': False},
             {'type': 'uint256', 'name': 'eth_sold', 'indexed': False},
             {'type': 'uint256', 'name': 'tokens_bought', 'indexed': False}],
  'anonymous': True,
  'type': 'event'},
 {'name': 'EthPurchase',
  'inputs': [{'type': 'address', 'name': 'buyer', 'indexed': False},
             {'type': 'uint256', 'name': 'tokens_sold', 'indexed': False},
             {'type': 'uint256', 'name': 'eth_bought', 'indexed': False}],
  'anonymous': True,
  'type': 'event'},
 ...
]
```